# Is there a word for something you want in an abstract sense but wouldn't want in reality?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to separate the thing that I want (the desire?) from the effort it would take to get it, or the consequences that come with obtaining it.

A noun or verb or phrase will do:

"I would love to have pin-up worthy abdominal muscles" (but I'm not willing to put in the sustained effort to actually get them)

"That girl is so attractive, I would love to have sex with her" (but I'm happily married and I wouldn't actually jeopardise my marriage by doing it)

"It's a dream of mine to perform at some amazing location" (but I'm not actually going to pursue performing as a career to make it possible)

Comment: 'Fantasy' seems like a good fit.

Comment: @peerless You should probably write that as an answer then :)  I think it has the same problems as dream - there are fantasies that should remain just so, and there are fantasies that you actively work on realising your whole life even though they may never happen.

Comment: If it doesn't fit what you had in mind, let it be a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be *hypothetical* or to talk *hypothetically*.

Definition:

> by imagining a possibility rather than reality; as a hypothesis.

Example:

> we talked hypothetically about how cool it would be if we moved

Above definition and example taken from the dictionary.

Comment: I think this is probably going to be the best fit for what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**a pipe dream**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+pipe+dream)

> If you describe something that someone wants to do or happen as a pipe
>   dream, you mean that it is not realistic and will probably not happen.

Comment: I had forgotten this phrase - I think it fits better than dream with that extra word.

Comment: I second this as well!

Answer (score 1):

A ***whim*** is defined by Collins English Dictionary<sup>1</sup> as:

> 1. a sudden, passing, and often fanciful idea; impulsive or irrational thought

And by the American Heritage Dictionary<sup>2</sup> as:

> 1. A sudden or capricious idea; a fancy

---

<sup>1<sub>whim. (n.d.) Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014). Retrieved May 15 2018 from https://www.thefreedictionary.com/whim</sub></sup>

<sup>2<sub>whim. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved May 15 2018 from https://www.thefreedictionary.com/whim</sub></sup>

Comment: To me, whim conjures up something that I didn't want yesterday, want now, but might not want tomorrow.  Very fleeting.  Good word though.

Comment: @PaulSmith - I’d classify your girl example and your abs example as fleeting.  They may come up repeatedly over time but they are just “fanciful ideas” that you have no intention of acting on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say ***[dream](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dream)*** is a good fit:

> to indulge in daydreams or fantasies (e.g., dreaming of a better future)

So you could say:

> I dream of having pinup-worthy abs
>
> I dream of having sex with that beautiful girl
>
> I dream of performing at some amazing location

Note that *dream* doesn't inherently suggest you're not going to follow through on your goals—you may very well *realize* your dreams. However, it *does* distance you from the subject of the dream as compared to words like *aspire* and *plan*.

Comment: I guess you're right, dream is more distanced than aspire and plan, I was wondering if there was a word even further along the scale than dream.

Answer (score 0):

[**In theory**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20theory), I would like to perform at Carnegie Hall. But I can't see that ever happening.

Comment: I don't like this one because it feels like it needs the 2nd sentence to form a complete thought.

Comment: @PaulSmith You could also say, "My performance is only theoretical." But I agree that for simplistic expressions, some of the other answers might be better. (Although I would likely use "theory" as I did if I was speaking about something at more length.)